# Regex help for .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, regex

I want to exclude access to certain files using .htaccess files but i need help generating the correct regexp.

I want to exclude access to these two files:

```
soft1-pp_1.12-123456789010_amd64.deb
soft1-tt_1.12-123456789010_amd64.deb
```

Version numbers are changing (1.12-123456789010) and I want the FilesMatch to work even after the versions change. What's the correct RegExp for it?

My .htaccess will be as following:

```
<FilesMatch "^(filename1|filename2)\.deb$">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Usually people will be more willing to help if you show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regexp:

```
^soft1-(pp|tt)_[.0-9-]*_amd64\.deb$
```